# How to transfer the name of the selected line in the List to another view in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, list, row

I am trying to create a list of sports activities, where in the view named Activity the user in another view called Add activity selects the type of sport and its subcategory in the Name of the activity line. But how do I pass the name of the marked subcategory from the Add Activity view to the Activity view to the Activity Name row? I find examples everywhere, how to pass data from TextField, etc ... But from the lines in my case, please, how do I pass data? The activity view is in my OneView file and the Add Activity view is in my TwoView file.

OneView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct OneView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var title: String = ""
    @State private var AktSel: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
          List{
                    Section(header: Text("Add activity")) {
                     Text("Title")
                        HStack {
                           Button(action: {
                             withAnimation{
                                    AktSel.toggle()
                                }
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Activity name")
                                  .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $AktSel) {
                                        TwoView()
                                   }
                               })
                        }
                    }
                }
              .navigationBarItems(leading:
            Button(action: {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                 }){
            Text("Done")
                         .font(.system(size: 20))
                     
             })
            
            .navigationBarTitle("Activity")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .font(.subheadline)
           
        }
    }
}

struct OneView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        OneView()
    }
}
```

TwoView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct TwoView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State var selected: String? = nil
 
    var Aerobikitems = ["Fitness aerobic", "Comercial aerobic", "Sprots aerobic", "Step aerobic"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    DisclosureGroup {
ForEach(Aerobikitems, id: \.self) { item in
                                                    SelectionRow(title: item, selected: $selected)
                                              }
                    } label: {
                    Text("Aerobic")
                }
                    }
                }
            .navigationBarTitle("Add activity")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                Button(action: {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                     }){
                Text("Done")
                             .font(.system(size: 20)) 
                 })
            }
        }
    }

struct TwoView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TwoView()
    }
}
```

SelectionRow.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct SelectionRow: View {
    
    typealias Action = (String) -> Void
    
    let title: String
    @Binding var selected: String?
    var action: Action?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(title)
            Spacer()
            if title == selected {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            }
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture {
            if title == selected {
                selected = nil
            } else {
                selected = title
            }
            
            if let action = action {
                action(title)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SelectionRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SelectionRow(title: "NoName", selected: .constant("NoName"))
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help and efforts

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood well *where* exactly you want the name of the subcategory to be passed to. If I assume you want it to appear where now we see "Activity name", the solution is quite simple.

Actually, you are already using it between `TwoView` and `SelectionRow`: passing a `@State` to a `@Binding`. You would just need to transfer the state (meaning, the "source of truth") from `TwoView` to `OneView`.

See how I changed your code here below, I hope this helps.

OneView:

```
struct OneView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var title: String? = nil     // Here you have the state, your "source of truth"
    @State private var AktSel: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                Section(header: Text("Add activity")) {
                    Text("Title")
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation{
                                AktSel.toggle()
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            Text(title ?? "Select an activity")     // Show the subcategory here, is that it??
                                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $AktSel) {
                                    TwoView(selected: $title)       // Pass the state to TwoView
                                }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                    Button(action: {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }){
                Text("Done")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                
            })
            
            .navigationBarTitle("Activity")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .font(.subheadline)
            
        }
    }
}
```

TwoView:

```
struct TwoView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var selected: String?          // This is a Binding, it handles the value from OneView
    
    var Aerobikitems = ["Fitness aerobic", "Comercial aerobic", "Sprots aerobic", "Step aerobic"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    DisclosureGroup {
                        ForEach(Aerobikitems, id: \.self) { item in
                            SelectionRow(title: item, selected: $selected)
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Aerobic")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Add activity")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                    Button(action: {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }){
                Text("Done")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
            })
        }
    }
}
```